# vscode bug: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to vs code. I want to know how to build a project using vs code.

When I run a c++ code in vs code, it report bug:

```
C:\usr\bin\g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\qiang_zhang\Desktop\vscode\demo.cpp -o C:\Users\qiang_zhang\Desktop\vscode\demo.exe
spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT generation finish, but error happen

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

[image: How can I fix this bug?]

But, if I run this code by: `right click-->Run Code(ctrl+alt+N)`, it can run correctly.

[image]

How can I fix the bug: `spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT`?